# How can I check internet traffic for the last month

Tags: docker, networking, traffic, network-traffic, ifconfig

I using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

In ifconfig I have many interfaces. How can I check only Internet traffic without considering local data exchange (for example, data exchange with docker containers or data exchange locally)?

My interfaces:

```
# ifconfig | grep 'Link encap' | awk '{print $1}'
br-0a...
br-13...
br-13...
br-23...
br-24...
br-36...
br-44...
br-7b...
br-8d...
br-c8...
docker0...
ens32
ens33
lo
veth0...
veth1...
veth2...
veth4...
veth4...
veth5...
veth6...
veth9...
veth9...
vetha...
vetha...
vethb...
vethc...
vethc...
vethc...
vethc...
vethd...
vethe...
```